# jq - How to concatenate an array in json

Tags: arrays, json, concatenation, jq

Struggling with formatting of data in jq.  I have 2 issues.

1. Need to take the last array .rental_methods and concatenate them into 1 line, colon separated.
2. `@csv` doesn't seem to work with my query.  I get the error `string ("5343") cannot be csv-formatted, only array`

jq command is this (without the `| @csv`)

```
jq --arg LOC "$LOC" '.last_updated as $lu | .data[]|.[]| $lu, .station_id, .name, .region_id, .address, .rental_methods[]'
```

JSON:

```
{
    "last_updated": 1539122087,
    "ttl": 60,
    "data": {
        "stations": [{
            "station_id": "5343",
            "name": "Lot",
            "region_id": "461",
            "address": "Austin",
            "rental_methods": [
                "KEY",
                "APPLEPAY",
                "ANDROIDPAY",
                "TRANSITCARD",
                "ACCOUNTNUMBER",
                "PHONE"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'd like the output to end up as:

```
1539122087,5343,Lot,461,Austin,KEY:APPLEPAY:ANDROIDPAY:TRANSITCARD:ACCOUNTNUMBER:PHONE:,
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `@csv`:

```
jq -r '.last_updated as $lu
  | .data[][]
  | [$lu, .station_id, .name, .region_id, .address, (.rental_methods | join(":")) ]
  | @csv'
```

What you were probably missing with `@csv` before was an array constructor around the list of things you wanted in the CSV record.

Answer (score 2):

You could repair your jq filter as follows:

```
.last_updated as $lu
| .data[][]
| [$lu, .station_id, .name, .region_id, .address, 
   (.rental_methods | join(":"))]
| @csv
```

With your JSON, this would produce:

```
1539122087,"5343","Lot","461","Austin","KEY:APPLEPAY:ANDROIDPAY:TRANSITCARD:ACCOUNTNUMBER:PHONE"
```

... which is not quite what you've said you want.  Changing the last line to:

```
map(tostring) | join(",")
```

results in:

```
1539122087,5343,Lot,461,Austin,KEY:APPLEPAY:ANDROIDPAY:TRANSITCARD:ACCOUNTNUMBER:PHONE
```

This is exactly what you've indicated you want except for the terminating punctuation, which you can easily add (e.g. by appending `+ ","` to the program above) if so desired.